# How to expand one-dimensional DataFrame to two-dimensional DataFrame with Boolean values?

Tags: python, pandas

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data = ['a','b','b','c'],index=['day1','day1','day2','day2'],columns=['name'])

     name
day1    a
day1    b
day2    b
day2    c
```

How can I convert df to a two-dimension DataFrame with boolean values like

```
      a  b  c
day1  1  1  0
day2  0  1  1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) *(Slower approach)* - Use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) to compute a frequency table of counts:

```
pd.crosstab(df.index, df['name'], rownames=[None]).rename_axis(None, 1)
```

2) *(Faster approach)* - Perform `Groupby` on the index axis and take respective [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) + `unstack` by filling missing values with 0:

```
df.groupby(level=0)['name'].value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0).rename_axis(None, 1)
```

Resulting output in both scenarios:

[image]